# Permission denied when running npm test via mocha and nyc on Travis-CI

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci, nyc

I'm setting up my server side for NodeJS application which I'm integrating with Travis-CI. I'm using Mocha and NYC to help with my tests. However, while these tests run fine locally, I'm failing the tests when on Travis-CI.

Locally everything works fine with no errors.

Travis-CI output error:

```
> server@1.0.0 test /server
> nyc --reporter=lcov npm run run-test "--coverage"
sh: nyc: Permission denied
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
The command "docker run repname/server npm test -- --coverage" exited with 1.
```

That's my .travis.yml file:

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
    
before_install:
  - docker build -t repname/server -f Dockerfile.dev .

script:
  - docker run repname/server npm test -- --coverage
```

I even tried some of other similar problems find on stack:
Thats what I tried with no luck:

For NYC:

```
before_script: chmod 0555 ./node_modules/.bin/nyc

before_script: chmod 0777 ./node_modules/.bin/nyc
```

For Mocha:

```
before_script: chmod 0555 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha

before_script: chmod 0555 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

Comment: This feels like node/npm get installed incorrectly, npm should have regular user rights by default. Is there a reason you need to run docker in travis rather than having a travis config that sets up the same environment as your docker container does for local work?

Comment: I want to push docker repo from travis, then I want to use env variables from travis to connect it further to google developer platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I wasn't add the right path in `.gitignore` file. So when I push to master on github, it actually pushed the `node_modules` folder, which was not supposed to do.

**Keep that in mind when you try to build on Travis CI or any CI, don't put your module folder in your main repo.**